# PowerQuery OR in Filtered Rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

My query currently has a Filtered Rows step of = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Confirming Sales Rep] = "Spencer Farris")). I need to also include anything where [Not Sold Original Non Sale Reason Employee] = "Spencer Farris."
I've tried a few variations of OR and commas, but can't get anything to work so I see everything of both filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UI:

- Select the `[Confirming Sales Rep]` column and filter on "Spencer Farris"
- Select the  `[Not Sold Original Non Sale Reason Employee]`  and filter on "Spencer Farris"
- Open the `Advanced Editor`
- On the `#"Filtered Rows"` step you will see an `and` separating the two clauses.

  - change the `and` to an `or`

Probably need something like:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Confirming Sales Rep] = "Spence Farris") or  ([Not Sold Original Non Sale Reason Employee] = "Spencer Farris"))
```